# Looping through records in an excel document

Tags: php, excel, loops

I need to loop through some records within an excel file and output them as headings for an HTML table but I don't know what is the best approach as I am new to PHP.

Each the column headings begins as a Title followed by an index so you have:

Country1, Country2, Country3 ....through to Country50.

I would like to have a more automatic way to retrieve these values rather than stick to the

$result .= "$Country1";

each  must also contain the id of the country which should also be converted into an array i.e. The other thing  so they do not require to be printed if that's the case, so the results could be

```
<th id="Country1">Value of Country1</th>
<th id="Country2">Value of Country2</th>
<th id="Country3">Value of Country3</th>
<th id="Country8">Value of Country8</th>
<th id="Country24">Value of Country24</th>
<th id="Country30">Value of Country30</th>
```

What is the best "code light" approach to doing this?

Regards!

Comment: Is this a real Excel file or a CSV file? Do you know how to read in the that file? Or do you just need help transforming the data into an HTML table? Also, please explain why you have to have the IDs. You can access individual nodes with CSS and JavaScript without them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gordon. Don't worry about reading the Excel file for now. I am using a borrowed script which retrieves the data and loops through the record. I need the id's because the html is aimed at a developer which will need to see the source code id for each th.

Answer (score 0):

something like that should work:

```
<?php
$handle = @fopen("/tmp/myfile.csv", "r");
if ($handle) {

    // first line should be the header, we make it an array of strings
    if ( ($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false )
      $headers[] = explode(",", $buffer);
    else
      echo "Error: empty file...\n";

    // second line should be the values, for each line we output the xml markups
    while ( ($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false )
    {
        $values[] = explode(",", $buffer);

        if( count($headers) != count(values) )
          echo "Error: the 2 lines do not have same number of columns...\n";
        else
        {
            for( $i = 0 ; $i < count($headers) ; $i++ )
              echo "<th id='".$headers[$i]."'>".$values[$i]."</th>\n";
        }
    }
    else
      echo "Error: second line empty...\n";

    if ( !feof($handle) )
      echo "Erreur: fgets() failed...\n";

    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```